# Share to Whatsapp using ImageButton android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio, whatsapp

I wanna share text to whatsapp using ImageButton, but I don't know how to set the ImageButton to share the text.

Here is my code

```
ImageButton wasap = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.wasapKongsi);
    Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
    whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, R.id.hadisView + "/n" + R.id.textView);
    try {
        startActivity(whatsappIntent);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(hadis.this, "Whatsapp have not been installed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I hope anyone here can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `ImageButton` `onClickListener`

```
     wasap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //your code here that you want to run
                Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
                whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, R.id.hadisView + "/n" + R.id.textView);
                try { 
                     startActivity(whatsappIntent);
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                     Toast.makeText(hadis.this, "Whatsapp have not been installed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } 
            }
     });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked. But, I wanna ask, why it appear numbers instead of text. Can you comment on my code?

Comment: Where are you take your text from? TextView? Complete complete code.

Comment: R.id.hadisView is the id of string not the acutual string, to get actual string use getString(R.id.hadisView);

Comment: What? You can't get string like this. First get reference to TextView and then call getString() method to get string. More info on how to use TextView http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Comment: I take my text from textView.